# RXjava2 method in fromCallable not getting exceuted

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am new to using rxjava and I am trying to run a function in background using rxjava2 but the method is not called the code I am using is given below let me know if its the right way to execute a function in background:

```
Observable.fromCallable<OrderItem>(Callable {
        saveToDb(existingQty, newOty, product_id)
    }).doOnSubscribe {
        object : Observable<OrderItem>() {
            override fun subscribeActual(emitter: Observer<in OrderItem>?) {
                try {
                    val orderItem = saveToDb(existingQty, newOty, product_id)
                    emitter?.onNext(orderItem)
                    emitter?.onComplete()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    emitter?.onError(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).doOnSubscribe {
        object : Observer<OrderItem> {
            override fun onComplete() {
            }

            override fun onNext(t: OrderItem) {

            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dong it wrong way. `doOnSubscribe()` operator is called when observable is subscribed using `subscribe()` method and you haven't subscribed the observable using `subscribe()` method.

You have called `saveToDb` method in `callable`, then why are you calling it in `doOnSubscribe`? it doesn't make sense.

You should have written following code:

```
Observable.fromCallable { saveToDb(existingQty, newOty, product_id) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ orderItem ->
                    // set values to UI
                }, { e ->
                    // handle exception if any
                }, { 
                    // on complete 
                })
```

to work with your logic.

Comment: Thanks I did'nt notice that I was calling dosubscribeOn..my bad

Answer (score 3):

`DoOnSubscribe` means "do when someone subscribe to it". But there is no `subscribe` in your code. Maybe you want to use `subsribe` instead of `doOnSubscribe`

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't notice that I was calling dosubscribeOn..my bad